# order two string_agg at same time

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a query that at some point has two aggregations:

```
string_agg(requirements, '@') as req, string_agg(name, ',') as name
```

Later on the code, I split the characters I used in the aggregation and zip the two resulting arrays together. However, this code will not work because I need the entries ordered by name. If I do this:

```
string_agg(requirements, '@') as req, string_agg(name, ',' order by name) as name
```

then it actually lose the correspondency with the requirements, once I split the strings and mount it again.

How can I order both aggregations at same time? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the same `order by` clause for both of them:

```
STRING_AGG(requirements, '@' ORDER BY name) AS req, 
STRING_AGG(name, ',' ORDER BY name) AS name
```

Comment: Although it is very likely that the two orderings will be the same there is no guarantee in the case of `name` ties. But again this is not important in this question since one of the aggretates is the name anyway.